# Native callback previous value of text input using JavaScript?

Tags: javascript, html, jquery

Edited:
I forgot to add a 'native' (for JS or browser) word to questions, as browsers (or JS i'm not sure) have a undo/redo feature in inputs, but it don't work with programmatically edited input and my main question is, if it is possible to add a code to trigger that native callback to previous value feature.
I tried to do this with document.execCommand paste/insertText but it didn't work and is marked as obsolete.

Old:
I have a custom action on keypress in input, for example where number have changed sign(+-) when '-' button is pressed.

I want to add that action to native undo/redo (ctrl+z/y) history stack, with preventing others default actions triggered when button responsible for my action is clicked.

Is this possible?
If no, to remove current, native undo/redo input feature, using event.preventDefault in crtl+z/y click detection would be enough? To replace it by custom undo/redo.

Is this dependable on browser?
I experimented with code on Firefox and Edge.

Is there something like [History API](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/History_API) for input available for JS and where i can read about it and how it is named in code?

As for similar topics in stack are old and i tried them but they didn't work (or i used them in wrong way).

```js
$(document).ready(function() {
  $(":input").on('keypress', function(e) {
      //On minus button click, reverse sign for number in input:
      if (e.key === '-') {
          e.preventDefault();
          //TODO: Add this change in input to undo/redo changes history:
          $(this).val(-$(this).val());
        }
  });
});
```

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<head>
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
</head>
<body>

  Number: <input type="text" name="num"><br>

</body>
</html>
```

Comment: You have to create your own queue system for undo/redo of state. There might be libraries you can use to help

Comment: To create custom undo/redo i need to know how to disable native undo/redo 1st. Mainly I'm looking how to add custom action (for example $('#input').val('text')) into native undo/redo feature from (JS or browser, i don't know its source.)

Answer (score 1):

### Simple Undo JS Script

You'll be able to capture event of (⌘ + z) or (CTRL + z). Therefore, you'll be able to preform this Undo JS implementation to have history stack of values every-time input changes.

**You should have Event Listener (input) either via DOM or jQuery e.g.**

```
$(":input").on('input', function (evt) {
console.log(this.value)
}
```

Now, you can trace any changes in input been targeted using jQuery Selector.

You should also define **global variables** inside your document, where you can track following:

1. History Stack (`historyValues`)
2. Steps To Take (`undoSteps`)
3. Maximum Steps (`maxSteps`)
4. Current Step (`currentUndo`)

**Source Code**

```js
// Global Varaibles (Controls)
 
var historyValues = [''];
var undoSteps = 2;
var maxSteps = 1;
var currentUndo = 1;

// Add event listener to track input changes and update historyValues
$(":input").on('input', function (evt) {
    historyValues.push(this.value);
    maxSteps = historyValues.length;
    //console.log(historyValues);
    
    // Check if 'Undo' been used if yes reset cause input been changed
    if (undoSteps !== 2) {
       undoSteps = 2;
    }
});
 

$(document).ready(function() {
 $(":input").on('keydown', function(e) {

    if (undoSteps > maxSteps) {
    // When you run out of backward steps, reset steps
       undoSteps = 1;
    }
    // Edited: Supports (⌘ + z and CTRL + z)
    if ( (e.ctrlKey && e.key === 'z') || (e.metaKey && e.key === 'z') ) {
        e.preventDefault();
        // Ensure 'currentUndo' not less than 0
        if (currentUndo >= 0) {
        
        // tracking steps backward
        currentUndo = (maxSteps - undoSteps);

        // Get previous value from history array
        var newValue = historyValues[currentUndo];
        
        $(this).val(newValue);
        
        // Add +1 steps as we used undo once
        undoSteps++;
        }
    }
});
});
```

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<head>
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
</head>
<body>

  Number: <input type="text" name="num"><br>

</body>
</html>
```

Answer (score 1):

i3z slighty enchanted answer:

1. Ctrl+z instead of '-' button for Undo action.
2. Fixed bug with 2 clicks needed to use undo action after adding new element.
3. Sign change action from my question is added to code.
4. Added empty "" as default in history stack.

```js
// Global Varaibles
// Edited: Added empty undo element, fixed undo working from 2nd click after adding new element to history.
var historyValues = [''];
var undoSteps = 2;
var maxSteps = 1;
var currentUndo = 1;

// Add event listener to track input and update historyValues
$(":input").on('input', function (evt) {
    historyValues.push(this.value);
    maxSteps = historyValues.length;
    //console.log(historyValues);
    
    // Check if 'Undo' been used if yes reset cause input been changed
    if (undoSteps !== 2) {
       undoSteps = 2;
    }
});
 
$(document).ready(function() {
 $(":input").on('keydown', function(e) {
    if (undoSteps > maxSteps) {
    // When you run out of backward steps, reset steps
       undoSteps = 1;
    }
    // check for key (Edited: changed to z) and ensure 'currentUndo' not less than 0
    if (e.ctrlKey && e.key === 'z' && currentUndo >= 0) {
        e.preventDefault();
        // tracking steps backward for every-time key '-' pressed
        currentUndo = (maxSteps - undoSteps);
        //console.log(maxSteps+' maxSteps - undoSteps '+undoSteps);
        // Get previous value from history array
        var newValue = historyValues[currentUndo];
        //console.log(currentUndo+' current - value '+newValue);
        $(this).val(newValue);
        // Add +1 steps as we used undo once
        undoSteps++;
    }
});
    
$(":input").on('keypress', function(e) {    
    //Edited: Added custom action on key '-' press
    if (e.key === '-') {
        e.preventDefault();
        $(this).val(-$(this).val());
        //Trigger history
        $(this).trigger('input');
      }
  });
});
```

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<head>
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
</head>
<body>

  Number: <input type="text" name="num"><br>

</body>
</html>
```